# Positioning my 'flipping' circle in the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a circle with content in it which not only flips but also levitates... I would like to ensure this circle is placed in the middle of the users browser, for some reason it (I believe its due to the flip) the circle is not centered.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvfywmac/)**

HTML

```
<div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="circle floating">
                            <img src="http://mogul.london/images/logo-home.png" width="217" height="107">
                            <span class="title">Title</span>
                            <span class="subline">Subtitle here</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="circle floating">
                            <span class="calltext">Call us now on</span>
                            <span class="number">000 000 0000</span>
                            <span class="ordertext">to order or make a reservation</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:#fff;
}

.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg); /* for firefox 31 */
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.circle {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 73, 0.67);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 85px 35px;
    display: inline-block;

    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    border-radius: 200px;
}

.circle span {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.circle span.title {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
}
.circle span.subline {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.circle span.calltext {
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.circle span.number {
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-size: 46px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.circle span.ordertext {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.floating{
    float: left;
    -webkit-animation-name: Floatingx;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-name: Floating;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Floatingx{
    from {-webkit-transform:translate(0, 0px);}
    65% {-webkit-transform:translate(0, 15px);}
    to {-webkit-transform: translate(0, -0px);    }    
}

@-moz-keyframes Floating{
    from {-moz-transform:translate(0, 0px);}
    65% {-moz-transform:translate(0, 15px);}
    to {-moz-transform: translate(0, -0px);}    
}
```

Comment: will your circle always be of the same size?

Comment: Yes they should be, they have been given a fixed size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrong calculated the width and height of `.flip-container`:

```
.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 370px; // .circle height + 2*padding = 300 + 2*35
    height: 385px; // .circle width + 2*padding + animation translate = 200 + 2*85 + 15
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvfywmac/2/) (Also, I removed the margin in `.floating`)

Comment: Okay that looks like it works, but there was no margin in `.circle` :/

Comment: Hmm theres a problem, the problem exists still in Safari. Any ideas?

Comment: For better browser support replace `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);` to `margin-top: -192.5px; margin-left: -185px;` in `.flip-container` (or use with [webkit prefix](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform))

Comment: Completely forgot to add these!

Answer (score 0):

assign the following styles e.g. to your container div or your circle:

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
width:400px;
margin-left:-200px
height:400px;
margin-top:-200px
```

use this css to center it i nthe middle of your page.
How it works: It positions the upper left corner exactly in the center and then the negative margin will "pull it back" upwards & to the left. (margin is always half of width and height)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

with this your circle is center and animate => levitation

```
#container{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background:rgba(255, 0, 73, 0.67);
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:auto auto;
    -webkit-animation: levite 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes levite{
    from {-webkit-transform:translate(0, 0);}
    65% {-webkit-transform:translate(0, 15px);}
    to {-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);    }    
}
```

<kbd>[see run](http://jsfiddle.net/cjk0a8x7/)</kbd>